# Best way to pass object to child component

Tags: reactjs

It's very interesting to know - is there difference in performance between

`<Child data={{...// some props here}}/>`

and

```
render() {
    const data = {...}
    return <Child data={data}/>
}
```

I read about functions. That it is better to replace inline functions 
from:

```
<button
    onClick={() => {
        ...
    }}
/>
```

To:

```
handleClick = () = {...}

...

<button
    onClick={this.handleClick}
/>
```

And what about passing objects?

Comment: Bad for handlers not for passing data. :) Helpful link: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
    const data = {...}
    return <Child data={data}/>
}
```

The `data` should be outside `render()`, because when some states are change, the `render()` method will be recall, and the `data` will be set again and again. So for performance, better declare it outside `render()`

Answer (score 1):

If the object is not derived from state or props and always be constant then better declare it outside the render method to avoid assigning the value to data every time the render method is called.

In comparison, for passing an object to a component both options(inline and assigning to a variable) are equivalent in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass all the props to child component from parent then you can do like:

```
<Child data={...this.props} />
```

But if you want to pass some props to that child component then you can take out those props in some constant and pass that constant to the child like:

```
const data = {data1: this.props.data1, data2: this.props.data2};
return <Child data={data}/>
```